# What do you think about clear of persistence context in each thred execution in implementing of session-per-request pattern?

Tags: multithreading, jpa, persistence

When you are working with JPA and implement session-per-request pattern (scope transaction in a thread's meaning) is it often needed for you to clear persistence context in each transaction's ending ? 
In my case, i do that because I save created entity managers in ThreadLocal's instance, so when I use one and same EntityManager's instance per a thread. But time to time, when user executes new request an old persistence container is return by ThreadLocal, containing old persistence data. 
Do you think my solution is reasanable having in mind non-functional requirements for scalability and performance?

Thanks in advance guys, 
And best Regards, 
Simeon

Answer (score 2):

If you have stale persistence contexts in new requests, you implemented session-per-request pattern incorrectly.

You need to close `EntityManager` and remove it from `ThreadLocal` when processing of request is over. If you do so, you won't need to call `clear()` (except for the cases when it's actually needed, for example, for massive batch operations).